# AutoMapper, mapping one type in two different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have the following models:

```cs
public class Stuff
{
    ...
    public IList<Place> Places { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}

public class Place
{
    ...
    public IList<Stuff> Stuffs { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}

public class StuffEntity 
{
    ...
    public IList<PlaceStuffEntity> Places { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}

public class PlaceEntity 
{
    ...
    public IList<PlaceStuffEntity> Stuffs { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}

public class PlaceStuffEntity
{
    public int StuffId { get; private set; }
    public StuffEntity Stuff { get; set; } = null!;
    public int PlaceId { get; private set; }
    public PlaceEntity Place { get; set; } = null!;
}

cfg.CreateMap<StuffEntity, Stuff>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Places,
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Places.Select(y => y.Place).ToList()));
cfg.CreateMap<PlaceEntity, Place>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Stuffs,
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Places.Select(y => y.Stuff).ToList()));
cfg.CreateMap<PlaceAndStuffEntity, Stuff>()              // < -- Issue
   .IncludeMembers(entity=> entity.Stuff);
cfg.CreateMap<PlaceAndStuffEntity, Place>()              // < -- Issue
   .IncludeMembers(entity=> entity.Place);
```

by some reason when I add both last lines, conversion does not work ...

But if I add only one line for example for converting `PlaceAndStuffEntity` -> `Stuff` works only one conversion from `PlaceEntity` -> `Place`

```cs
var place = mapper.Map<Place>(placeEntity); // <- This works
var stuff = mapper.Map<Stuff>(stuffEntity); // <- Does not work !!
```

Is there a way properly handle the following conversions ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to map through the joining table (PlaceAndStuff) to get to the other entity type. For instance in your Place to get a list of Stuff, and Stuff to get a list of Place, you want to direct Automapper how to navigate through the joining table.

For instance:

```
cfg.CreateMap<StuffEntity, Stuff>()             
   .ForMember(x => x.Places, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PlaceEntity));
// Where StuffEntity.Places = PlaceAndStuffEntities, to map Stuff.Places use PlaceAndStuffs.PlaceEntity

cfg.CreateMap<PlaceEntity, Place>()             
   .ForMember(x => x.Stuffs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StuffEntity));
```

So rather than trying to tell EF how to map the joining entity PlaceStuffEntity, we focus on the PlaceEntity and StuffEntity, and tell Automapper to navigate through the joining entity to get at the actual Stuff and Place relatives via the joining entity.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cfg.CreateMap<PlaceEntity, Place>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Stuffs,
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Places.Select(y => y.Stuff).ToList()));
```

to

```
cfg.CreateMap<PlaceEntity, Place>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Stuffs,
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Stuffs.Select(y => y.Stuff).ToList()));
```

Source type PlaceEntity does not have a property named Places, only Stuffs.